# .Net Core: nvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

I try to run 6 tasks in Parallel and I get this error every once in a while:

> `InvalidOperationException:` An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A `DbContext` instance cannot be used inside `OnConfiguring` since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()`

**StartUp.cs**

```
services.AddDbContext<myDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Services I use in for the current tasks:

```
services.AddScoped<IPostService, PostService>();
services.AddScoped<IPartnerService, PartnerService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped<IRelatedRepository, RelatedRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<ICookieRepository, CookieRepository>();
```

The way I try to run my tasks and get exception:

```
var relatedTipsTask = Task.Run(() => GetRelatedTipsVms(citiesIDs, countriesIDs, categoriesIDs, bigNumToTake, tipID));
////#1.2 Get related texts widgets
var relatedTextsTask = Task.Run(() => GetRelatedTextsVms(citiesIDs, countriesIDs, categoriesIDs, smallNumToTake, textID));
////#1.3 Get related partners widgets
var relatedPartnersTask = Task.Run(() => GetRelatedPartnersVms(smallNumToTake, partnerID));
////#1.4 Get related post widgets
var relatedPostsTask = Task.Run(() => GetRelatedPostsVms(citiesIDs, countriesIDs, smallNumToTake, postID));
////#1.5 Get related businesses
var relatedBusinessesTask = Task.Run(() => GetRelatedBusinessVms(citiesIDs, countriesIDs, smallNumToTake, businessID));
////#1.6 Get related preflight
var relatedPreflightTask = Task.Run(() => GetRelatedPreflightVms(bigNumToTake, textID));
await Task.WhenAll(relatedTipsTask, relatedTextsTask, relatedPartnersTask, relatedPostsTask, relatedBusinessesTask, relatedPreflightTask);
```

Second question, When I run it like this it works fine but sync(not async), why is that?

```
//#1.1 Get related tips widgets
var relatedTipsTask = GetRelatedTipsVms(citiesIDs, countriesIDs, categoriesIDs, bigNumToTake, tipID);
//#1.2 Get related texts widgets
var relatedTextsTask = GetRelatedTextsVms(citiesIDs, countriesIDs, categoriesIDs, smallNumToTake, textID);
//#1.3 Get related partners widgets
var relatedPartnersTask = GetRelatedPartnersVms(smallNumToTake, partnerID);
//#1.4 Get related post widgets
var relatedPostsTask = GetRelatedPostsVms(citiesIDs, countriesIDs, smallNumToTake, postID);
//#1.5 Get related businesses
var relatedBusinessesTask = GetRelatedBusinessVms(citiesIDs, countriesIDs, smallNumToTake, businessID);
//#1.6 Get related preflight
var relatedPreflightTask = GetRelatedPreflightVms(bigNumToTake, textID);
await Task.WhenAll(relatedTipsTask, relatedTextsTask, relatedPartnersTask, relatedPostsTask, relatedBusinessesTask, relatedPreflightTask);
```

Comment: Using `Task.Run` in ASP.NET will only burn threads. Why are you doing it?

Comment: To make it work in parallel

Comment: Is that work IO?

Comment: It's DB, so yes

Comment: So, it's inheritably asynchronous. `Task.Run` just burns threads.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you did was clearly a violation of what is being stated in Microsoft's doc. about Entity Framework Core.

> Entity Framework Core does not support multiple parallel operations being run on the same DbContext instance

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

The main difference between your 2 execution styles above is that the first one causes multiple threads to try to utilize DB context. I would suggest that you make your repo. methods. asynchronous (EF Core has built-in async. methods), and let the framework manages the resources, rather than using Task.Run to execute IO tasks.

Also, the rule of thumb, Task.Run for CPU-bound task, whereas async/await for I/O-bound task.

Comment: Thanks, It is right. `Entity Framework Core does not support multiple parallel operations being run on the same DbContext instance`

Comment: @YYTan: Are you saying having a series of async calls back to back to back is the solution. Microsoft says this is an anti-pattern? That is why Task.Whenall() was created.

Comment: @FlyingV I have not read anywhere which says having back to back async call is anti-pattern. Anyway, I am simply addressing the issue faced by OP. If you have a series of methods which involves accessing dbcontext, then they should not run in parallel. One way I could think of making the above code works in parallel is by creating a scoped service for each of the method, but that's really ugly. I would say the async-await is just a recommendation to prevent parallel access to the db context, and how it's being used to manage the flow of program in that method is up to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios

This is the proper way to run several background tasks in a nonblocking manner. If it makes you feel better, i made the same mistake. :)

```
public async Task<User> GetUserAsync(int userId)
{
    // Code omitted:
    //
    // Given a user Id {userId}, retrieves a User object corresponding
    // to the entry in the database with {userId} as its Id.
}

public static async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsersAsync(IEnumerable<int> userIds)
{
    var getUserTasks = new List<Task<User>>();
    foreach (int userId in userIds)
    {
        getUserTasks.Add(GetUserAsync(userId));
    }

    return await Task.WhenAll(getUserTasks);
}
```